# log4j2 StringMapMessage can not get custom message

Tags: java, log4j2

Here is my StringMapMessage :

```
object Messages {

final case class SimpleMapMessage(id: String, ai: String, runtime: Long, msg: String) extends StringMapMessage {
   put("id", id)
   put("ai", ai)
   put("runtime", String.valueOf(runtime / (1000 * 1000.0)))

 override def formatTo(buffer: lang.StringBuilder): Unit = 
    buffer.append(msg)
 }

 def event(event: ChartEvent, message: String): Message = {
   val context = event.context
   val runtime = System.nanoTime() - event.started
   SimpleMapMessage(context.id, context.ai, runtime, message)
 }
}
```

The case class:

```
case class ChartEvent(...)
```

Here I can call it:

```
logger.info(Messages.event(event, "test something"))
```

But I got this out:

```
 ... ai="0a1b4118dd954ec3bcc69da5138bdb96" id="fa507bd79f6adf308aedcb7f1daef8c7" runtime="298.690142"
```

I cant not get the message "test something"

**Update:**

It works well in version **2.8.2**. But failed in version **2.11.1**

The full log here:

```
2018-08-21 02:59:34.988 [INFO] ${map:id} ${map:ai} ${map:runtime} from  classA - ai="0a1b4118dd954ec3bcc69da5138bdb96" id="72f8ec5a1a3073b213d094127aca94c4" runtime="137.950475"
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the shown code: this method/constructor takes a `msg: String` argument but doesn’t do anything with it so it’s just dropped...

```
final case class SimpleMapMessage(
      id: String, 
      ai: String, 
      runtime: Long, 
      msg: String)
   put("id", id)
   put("ai", ai)
   put("runtime", ...
  // need to put msg String also
```

Comment: Where can I report this bug if it is.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I misunderstood. Please report this on the log4j 2 jira issue tracker.